# Programmatically creating Hangfire cron expression based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron, cronexpression, hangfire

I have a C# .NET web application with a UI that looks similar to http://www.cronmaker.com/. The user can select the frequency of a job from many options. I need to be able to create a cron expression to represent the user's desired frequency, and it must be compatible with Hangfire. My ideas were to either:

1. Find an existing library that does it. But I haven't been able to. I heard that Quartz could do it (though it would be overkill), but it seemed that it could create cron expressions for some cases but not others.
2. Make my own tool, using cronmaker.com to figure out the format. However, cronmaker creates cron expressions in a format that Hangfire considers invalid. For "every hour," cronmaker says "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *" which Hangfire said was invalid. I found that "0 */1 * * *" works.

I need to be able to dynamically generate any cron expression. Surely there's a library out there that can do something like CronLibrary.GetCronExpression(Frequency.EveryNDays, 3, "12:00") with options to cover every conceivable situation. Does anyone know of such a library ?

Comment: Could you better define the question you are asking?

Comment: I have a page that looks like cronmaker.com. The user uses radio buttons, dropdowns, and textboxes to indicate the desired frequency, e.g., "every 5 minutes," "every weekday at 9 am," or "the first Monday of every month." Whatever frequency they indicate, I need to create the corresponding cron expression. How do I do that?

Comment: @Robin Let me try asking a different way. I see people asking "What's the cron expression for every day at midnight," and someone responds with a string literal for that specific situation. But I don't just need a specific cron expression; I need to be able to dynamically generate any cron expression.

Surely there's a library out there that can do something like

CronLibrary.GetCronExpression(Frequency.EveryNDays, 3, "12:00")

with options to cover every conceivable situation.

Comment: Seems like cron expressions can have different formats depending on the system used e.g. Unix, Hangfire or Quartz. I don't see a detailed document from Hangfire about their flavour of the cron expression - do you have that link?

Comment: @Robin, I'm afraid I wasn't able to find a link about Hangfire's cron syntax. Also, to clarify the edit, a library is not the only solution, it's just what seemed like the most obvious solution. Another possible solution would be if there's a site out there like cronmaker.com, but which generates cron expressions that are valid for Hangfire - then I could use that as a model to write my own code to convert the user's input into cron expressions.

Comment: I make use of NCronTab and CronExpressionDescriptor for most of my C# Cron needs. Both are on NuGet. YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a library, but the site http://crontab.guru/ was tremendously helpful for creating cron expressions that are valid for Hangfire. Using that site as a reference, I was able to write code to map the UI selections to a cron expression and vice versa.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your code for this? I need exactly the same thing! :D